# Web Service Passing Value error (asmx)

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I have a web service

```
[WebMethod]
public void Insert(int node, int date, int time, int rtt)
{

    string query = "INSERT INTO pingresult (node, date, time, rtt) VALUES('"+node+"', '"+date+"', '"+time+"', '"+rtt+"')";

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {              
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
    this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

and when i tried to using the method

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    int node, date, time, rtt;
    PingService.Service1 s1 = new ConsoleApplication1.PingService.Service1();          

    node = 1;
    date = 090512;
    time = 1720;
    rtt = 2222;

    s1.Insert(node,date,time, rtt);           
 }
```

and i got this error 
**No overload for method 'Insert' takes '4' arguments**

Any Idea?
I have look for the solution at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320207/webservice-c-sharp-constructor-does-not-allow-arguments) but i dont really know what it means

Comment: I think you would be better off using string not int here

Comment: You are converting them to strings when you insert anyway, and date isnt an integer anyway

Comment: I tried string but the problem still there. actually I compiled this within a local machine it cause no error, but when it comes to web service, the problem is occurred like what I mentioned, and i totally  got no clue on it..

Comment: Also note that `if (this.OpenConnection() == true)` can just be `if (this.OpenConnection())`. That won't help your issue, but just fyi.

Comment: okok, noted, thanks for your advice ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my stupid mistake where I didn't update my Web Reference in my client side, and I found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392247/no-overload-for-the-method-xyz-with-out-parameters-take-4-arguments) and thanks for those who give advices.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer. I don't know why I didn't think to suggest that. I've done the same thing myself.

Comment: Haha, sometime the human mistakes drive us crazy, but im really thanks for your help ^^